# General Database Query runner

Tags: database, architecture, integration

I have this problem where I need to provide an interface for users to run a query on a database containing *timeseries* data that they control and have access to. My system just needs to act as a the "runner" of the database query they want to execute against. I'm looking to see if there are any off the shelf tools in open source or otherwise which can handle the task of taking a generic query as a string, some authentication information and endpoint data and then make the request on my behalf.

I know that logstash has a JDBC tool: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html

which might work, but I am curious if anyone knows of other projects I should look at for additional information.

Ideally the system would take in the following information:

```
    query: string; // The query to be executed
    startTime: string; // The start time of the query
    endTime: string; // The end time of the query
    valueKey: string; // The keyName of the value to be operated on per row by the aggregation function
    endPoint: string // The Endpoint DNS or IP to query against
    authentication : BasicAuth | BearerAuth | ...
```

Additionally it doesn't necessarily need to take in a time range, its possible that I could filter out the data afterwards.

Comment: Are you looking for Grafana?

Comment: Graphana could potentially could work, however I don't see any way of programatically create, run and update queries from their API documentation here: 
https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/http_api/

Ideally the system would be "headless" and fairly lightweight. Their agent I believe fits the headless and lightweight category, but it appears to me to be more for ingestion of data to a different datasink rather than querying data.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Grafana itself does not support data ingestion. You can connect to datasources from it and execute queries against them. The results then can be visualized by utilizing different panels. In other words Grafana is a dashboarding tool, not a data collection/ingestion service.

Comment: After spending a bit more time looking into it, you're right that Graphana could work for my needs, however its not really an officially supported API to run a query via the API call. 

https://community.grafana.com/t/is-it-possible-to-execute-sql-queries-from-grafana-apis/34921